# Unable to find client_secret.json with Google Calendar API in python

Tags: python, api, google-calendar-api

I followed the instructions on this [website](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python) to quick start with google Calendar API with python. I had no problem with the steps 1 to 3, I generated a json document from the google API website and copied it in my working directory along with the python file **quickstart.py** but when I try to run the program from the windows console I get this error:

```
oauth2client.clientsecrets.InvalidClientSecretsError: ('Error opening file', 'client_secret.json', 'No such file or directory', 2)
```

I don't understand where to place the file **client_secret.json** for it to be recognized.

If you have any idea that could help me please share !

Thank you :)

Comment: is the client_secret.json in the same folder as the quickstart.py?

Comment: yes it is in the same folder

Comment: Okay, this error always is what it says: an addressing issue. If you are certain there are no typos, and u are sure they are in the same directory ( cause you might have two copies of quickstart.py and you are working with a different copy ) then try passing the absolute path to credentials.json